# iOS App Content Goes Blank when not in focus

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, focus

I used a package from Salesforce as a basis for my iPad iOS app, and whenever I take the app out of focus with the home button (as per the image) the app goes blank like some sensitive banking apps do - which I don't want.

I'm sure it's some prop in XCode, but I've looked and I can't find it.

The app is the center app below, and as you can see it appears blank when not in focus.

[image: The app is Voice, and as you can see it appears blank when not in focus.]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Still struggling with this!